# Удаление значка приложения WPF из свойств

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio, .net-6

Доброе утро! Указал иконку приложения в свойствах проекта. Хочу удалить её, а она не удаляется. Как мне это сделать? Уже и сам файл заменил/удалил - пишет ошибку, мол он не может его найти.

Visual Studio 2022, .NET6, WPF

Answer (score 2):

Дважды кликаем на `название всего проекта` (не решения) в обозревателе решений. В открывшемся файле в разделе `PropertyGroup` удаляем строчку `ApplicationIcon`. Сохраняем.

> Только что узнал об этом файле, кликая по всему, что есть. Прошу не судить строго за такой банальный вопрос и быстрый самоответ.